# how to get percentage of similarity using libfacerec Opencv library

Tags: c++, opencv, percentage, face-recognition

It might be an easy question but i am bit confuse so hope some one guide me properly.

i am using face recognition library of openCV libfacerec , it gives good result but i need to estimate the percentage of similarity. If i use unknown image as an input then still it predict as if the person exist in the system on the basis of last distance value

```
         if(dist < minDist) {
        minDist = dist;
        minClass = _labels[sampleIdx];
    }
```

I need to define some threshold and then validate/invalidate the user picture based on that threshold against some percentage or distance value, does any one know how to do that using libfacerec library because in this library there is no public variable to see distance or percentage value? Otherwise do i need to code inside the library for it because as far as i understand it does not contain this feature???

Comment: Hi. I searched in the doc, but couldn't find a simple way to get this without digging in the code either. You might directly want to post an issue on Gituh, where the project is hosted : https://github.com/bytefish/libfacerec/issues. I am sure the dev will get back to you quickly !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please make sure you are working on the latest revision! The latest revision of libfacerec allows you to get a predicition AND a confidence value for the prediction. You can see the signature of the methods here:

- https://github.com/bytefish/libfacerec/blob/master/include/facerec.hpp

It is shown in the demo application I ship with the library, please see:

- https://github.com/bytefish/libfacerec/blob/master/samples/facerec_demo.cpp

It's as simple as calling:

```
FaceRecognizer::predict(InputArray src, int &label, double &confidence);
```

on a computed model. So in your application you would simply write:

```
Mat testSample; // of course this is set somewhere in your application
int predictedLabel = -1;
double confidence = 0.0;
model.predict(testSample, predictedLabel, confidence);
```

Then you have the predicted label in predictedLabel AND the confidence value for this prediction in confidence.

Second, and this probably fits your question even more, you now have the possibility to set a threshold, below which an input image is regarded as unknown. You can either set the threshold in the constructor of a model or with a setter/getter method:

- https://github.com/bytefish/libfacerec/blob/master/include/facerec.hpp (see createEigenFaceRecognizer, createFisherFaceRecognizer, createLBPHFaceRecognizer)

It is also shown in the demo application I ship with the library:

- https://github.com/bytefish/libfacerec/blob/master/samples/facerec_demo.cpp

Comment: Thanks bytefish ! it works like a charm one more thing GIT is not updating the whole source trunk directory. I had to update the whole trunk through the zip archive of libfacerec library. Also thanks for the offer i will surely in touch with you for the contribution.

Comment: Cool! I have prepared an updated version and I will upload it by sunday. It would be awesome if you could read through and tell me, where you see improvements/what's confusing.

Comment: Hello mr. bytefish. I've been using the latest revision of libfacerec also, but in python. Is there a way to also use this confidence value in the prediction in python? It would be helpful for my application to be able to say if a given person is unknown.

Comment: Mr. Bytefish. Hahaha, no need to be *that* polite! You mean [http://github.com/bytefish/facerec](http://github.com/bytefish/facerec)?

Comment: Well ok bytefish sir :p I am using one of the facerec examples in that package - apps/videofacerec/videofacerec.py to try out my face recognition, however, in that documentation I couldn't find anything refering to a threshold for accepting recognition of persons (I'm somewhat new to this, sorry).